# Amoebic Sea walking forms

Tags: creature-design, aliens, planets

[image]

My favorite part of Alien Planet is the Amoebic Sea. I love how surreal it is. The Sea Striders make it all the better. If I were to make my own amoebic sea, what factors would I need to consider in designing creatures to walk across the surface? Could something with more than two legs work? The more alien the better.

Comment: References are good. I don't know what Alien Planet or the Amoebic Sea is.

Comment: Alien planet is based on a book by Wayne Barlowe, Expedition,  you will find a lot of information there.

Answer (score 3):

***We're going to need a bigger boat...***

To make organisms to walk on your sea, the first thing is to understand the sea. Then the striders are a triviality - giant dust mites or ticks stealing from a huge organism.

Okay, so you want a giant living sea/organism. On a certain level, that makes it just like the real sea. But on another, it makes it essentially one giant organism. Functionally, it needs to behave a lot like an organism to be able to do what you want. You'll need to decide how extensive the interactions are with your sea, and how evolved it should be.

First up, it is likely to be a shallow sea, or else a covering over a deeper one. It may, in fact, only look flat - there could be a coating of Amoebic Sea like a giant slime layer covering the ground. If there is underlying water, the whole thing needs to be buoyant, or else have structural components holding it up.Giant striders may need to be light to avoid braking through the coating of the sea. Maybe they're big because they are full of hydrogen bladders to lift it up.

Energy needs to power your Amoebic Sea, so one of the organisms will likely be a photosynthetic one (likely multiple ones). To get energy, those organisms need to have light, and with something this dense, that means near the surface. The sea will have the color of the predominant photosynthetic organism, be it green, orange, red, or whatever. There might be tendrils that take advantage of chemical energy (like thermal vents), but this will work because multiple species means multiple parts coordinating to take advantage of multiple environments.

For the sea to behave like an amoeba, it needs animals, so your sea can't be merely a giant gelatinous lichen. Predation is unlikely to be a primary source of nutrients for the sea, so this behavior is likely either mineral-seeking, defensive (think immune system) or both. If your sea is coordinated, then perhaps there are hollow spaces underneath with valves like heart valves to act as traps for walkers going over it. They fall "through", into a digestive pit. Large walkers may be too big to fit in these pits (a survival advantage) or too light (due to buoyant gasses or small size), or too wide (because they resemble huge spiders or centipedes). Multiple legs for stability on a mushy, aggressive surface would be valuable.

Your sea/organism will be producing it's own oxygen, but that will only diffuse so far. If the organism has any depth to it, there may be some sort of circulatory system for water & nutrients, gasses, or both.

The surface must be resistant to predation like a relatively clear leather. Maybe it is chemically like a thick plate of clear plastic, allowing light through yet being protective. A lot of plants like this would have thorny projections, but this isn't in theme with a smooth surface. In the giant dust mite model, this skin is what is eaten, not the underlying "tissue." Other models would have the walkers puncturing deeper to gain the protected water and nutrients. Perhaps then the walker feet have huge bony hypodermic needles that stab down into the sea like giant mosquitos.

Since the suggestion is that this sea is a collective, why are different parts working together? There needs to be a benefit for all parts to be coordinating and sharing. Selfish organisms in the collective benefit without "paying in," so there needs to be a responsive system to enforce communalism in something as organized as this, or else selfish species/cells will behave like cancer and eat up the rest. Mutation is likely to periodically result in a selfish spot, so the Amoebic Sea would have tumors, cancer, and an "immune" response to deal with this. Or perhaps the walkers are part of this system, and tumor parts don't defend themselves well, thus getting eaten by walkers.

These are my thoughts about the forces driving the Amoebic Sea and the walkers on it, and how the two are likely to interact. It's not a complete picture, but fill in what you like.

Comment: I was hoping for something a bit more about the mechanics of the striders. I was hoping for ideas for some really weird forms so I could make it unique