# Different Environment of Amoebic Sea

Tags: planets, aliens, environment, sea

I want to work with my own amoebic sea like on Darwin iv in the mockumentary Alien Planet. But I wonder if it would be the same throughout. Would the parts near the poles be frozen? Would shallow areas be any different?

Comment: I had an answer about a very similar question. Check out the numerous amoebic sea questions. Here is just one about the sea composition (which I discussed to explain how walkers would function.) Your question is more climate-based than anything else. Cold climates could likely live, but support a much smaller biomass. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/186732/amoebic-sea-walking-forms/186740#186740

Comment: So the amoebic layer would be thinner

Comment: I'm guessing. It would need something to keep it from freezing, it would have less energy due to the low light levels powering the plant portion of the thing, and so on. Thinner also means more vulnerable to storms, predation, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If food mold makes a good comparison with amoebic sea, I think that different conditions will lead to different local environments.

Like cheese tends to grow white-yellowish mold while fruit or jam grows a grey one, so for the amoebic sea differences based on the locale can influence the variety of the constituents: more cold resistant near the poles and more heat resistant near the equator, if the planet has an axial tilt that makes the poles cold and the equator hot.

Comment: I need more to go on. Like what the different areas might be like.

Comment: Paraphrasing Dutch here, who says they would be "like cheese...yellowish mold... fruit..jam."  I would include peanut butter.  Chunky and smooth.